# Bigquery using within with where

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the correct syntax for the following query in bigquery?
SELECT COUNT(children.names) WITHIN RECORD AS numberOfChildren FROM [dataset.tableId] where numberOfChildren > 10;

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a subselect and applying the filter to the outer select:

```
SELECT numberOfChildren FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(children.names) WITHIN RECORD AS numberOfChildren 
   FROM [dataset.tableId]
) 
WHERE numberOfChildren > 10;
```